# How to transfer from my Indian account to my US account as part of relocation

Tags: united-states, india, transfer

I am relocating from India to US. I would like to transfer my money from INR to USD .

1. Is there a limit on money transfer between my own accounts ?
2. Since the money is already taxed in India , will I have to pay taxes again in US ?
3. Will I be faced with any queries from IRS ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit on money transfer between my own accounts ?

Yes you need to follow FEMA. There is some paperwork that needs to be done. As per FEMA [[Foreign Exchange Management Act]](https://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/FEMA_FAQs.aspx), any transfer by individuals outside of India need the 15CA & 15CB form. The 15CB is from a CA to state that taxes have been paid on the funds being transferred. The limit is 1 million USD per year.
Read more at [Liberalized Remittance Scheme](https://rbi.org.in/Scripts/NotificationUser.aspx?Id=10192&Mode=0) and [here](https://www.rbi.org.in/Scripts/FAQView.aspx?Id=66).

> Since the money is already taxed in India , will I have to pay taxes again in US ?

There are no taxes. There maybe some reporting requirements on the tax returns in US.

> Will I be faced with any queries from IRS ?

No if the returns are filed appropriately.